# How to escape annotate text with superscript parse=TRUE?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot for which I need to add an annotation and then append a superscript to that annotated text. like so e.g.

```
p <- p + ggplot2::annotate('text', x, y, label=paste0(label,paste0("^", i)), parse=TRUE)
```

I iterate over some i and then want the label(i) to be superscripted with i. The problem is that I then get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol 
1: Super. Computer
           ^
```

Why isn't the char input `Super. Computer` good for parse? can I escape the text and leave only the appended superscript for parse to handle? something like `\text{Super. Computer}^1`

Is there any other way to just append a superscript to the annotated text?

**UPDATE** The answer below is not optimal see the two problems in this counter example:

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(latex2exp)

p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg))+ geom_point()

i <- 1
label <- "Super. Computer\n  of tomorrow"
p <- p + ggplot2::annotate('text', x=6, y=30,
                           label=TeX(paste0(label,paste0("^", i)), output="character"), 
                           fontface='bold',parse=TRUE)
print(p)
```

Problems:

1. fontface parameter is ignored
2. The spaces after \n are removed from the output
3. There is some gap to the right before the superscript

Comment: adjust any element with a space to a ~, something like like this "Super.~Computer"

Comment: This is good too but I get some multi-lines labels truncated ... I am still trying to find out why ... for example `Super Computer\n   in development` will not show the second line ... Ah I use `stringr::str_replace_all(label, '  ', '~')` to do it ...

Comment: yea, new lines and plotmath don't mix

Comment: `latex2exp` is very flexible but you need to use its syntax for a correct formatting of your text. I am aware that this requires an additional work. See the new example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on `latex2exp`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg))+ geom_point()

i <- 10
label <- paste0('\\textbf{$\\overset{Super.\\,\\,\\, Computer}{of\\, Tomorrow$^{',i,'}}}')
p <- p + ggplot2::annotate('text', x=6, y=30,
     label=TeX(label, output="character"), parse=TRUE)
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks! however, this solution is still not optimal for my use-case 1) my bold parameter to annotate is ignored or overwritten. 2) if there are multiple spaces in the label that I'd like to keep they are removed ...

Comment: Thanks!! Is it possible to nest multiple overset to get three or even four lines?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I suggest to consider the answer of Baptiste at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827373/equal-spacing-with-multiple-atop/45827869?noredirect=1#comment78613874_45827869